# Python Regex for ignoring a sentence with two consecutive upper case letters

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a simple problem at hand to ignore the sentences that contain two or more consecutive capital letters and many more grammar rules .

**Issue:** By the definition the regex should not match the string `'This is something with two CAPS.'` , but it does match.

**Code:**

```
''' Check if a given sentence conforms to given grammar rules

    $ Rules
        * Sentence must start with a Uppercase character (e.g. Noun/ I/ We/ He etc.)
        * Then lowercase character follows.
        * There must be spaces between words.
        * Then the sentence must end with a full stop(.) after a word.
        * Two continuous spaces are not allowed.
        * Two continuous upper case characters are not allowed.
        * However the sentence can end after an upper case character.
'''

import re


# Returns true if sentence follows these rules else returns false
def check_sentence(sentence):
    checker = re.compile(r"^((^(?![A-Z][A-Z]+))([A-Z][a-z]+)(\s\w+)+\.$)")
    return checker.match(sentence)

print(check_sentence('This is something with two CAPS.'))
```

**Output:**

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 32), match='This is something with two CAPS.'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s probably easier to write your regex in the negative (find all sentences that are bad sentences) than it is in the positive.

```
checker = re.compile(r'([A-Z][A-Z]|[ ][ ]|^[a-z])')
check2 = re.compile(r'^[A-Z][a-z].* .*\.$')
return not checker.findall(sentence) and check2.findall(sentence)
```

Comment: This is harder , I have a test suite and here are the results of that

Comment: Sorry . The sentence should be two words `'Hithere.'` should fail , but it doesn't. And the first Capital letter should be followed by atleast a single small letter.

Comment: So you can’t have the sentence "I am very happy."  That is a weird grammar:

Answer (score 0):

Your negative lookahead is only applying to the beginning of the string being tested.

2nd Capturing Group `(^(?![A-Z][A-Z]+))`

`^` asserts position at start of the string

Negative Lookahead `(?![A-Z][A-Z]+)`

`"This will NOT fail."`

`"THIS will fail."`

Comment: Thanks. Could you please write the modified regular expression .